# Draw a table with tkinter where cells need to be colored on click and retrieve by code the choices

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkiinter and i didn't manage to find a solution to my problem on internet.

First thing I need to draw a sort of table with triangles similar to the one in this picture (https://www.tilelook.com/system/tile_picture/resource/4973584/d3d_default_RE04MC017.png).

Then the user can choose a color somewhere (from a list or something similar) and change the color of a triangle by clicking on it. The most important thing is that i need to retrieve these information in the code (for each trinagle I need to know which color the user choosed).

Edit:
I still didn't write any code, but i know how to draw the table with Canvas and more or less how to handle the coloring part. The hard part for me is how to retrieve the informations in the code, I think it's like considering each element of the table like an independent object or something like that, but i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you show your working code or even an attempt at it? (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))this looks like an assignment and shows 0 effort on your part.

Comment: to draw triangel you will need `Canvas` and maybe objects with tags. You can use `Buttons` with different colors to choose color - but there should be dialog window for choosing color.

Comment: effbot.org: [tkinter color dialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-color-dialogs.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't give you a complete solution but you may find the below a helpful starting point

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import choice

def getRandomColor():
    return choice(['red','blue','green','yellow','white','goldenrod'])

def click(event):
    print(vars(event))
    item = event.widget.find_withtag('current')
    event.widget.itemconfig(item,fill=getRandomColor())

root = tk.Tk()
root.grid()

c = tk.Canvas(root,width=300,height=300,bg='black')
c.grid()
c.create_polygon(0,0,100,0,50,100,fill='blue',tag='tri_1')
c.create_polygon(100,0,50,100,150,100,fill='yellow',tag='tri_2')
c.bind('<Button-1>',click)

root.mainloop()
```

This will create two triangles. If you click on a triangle it will change to a random color (from a small list of colors). 
This will give you some ideas about 
a. drawing polygons on a tkinter canvas
b. binding a function to a click
c. changing the properties of a canvas item

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: Thank you, i think that creating each triangle as a new polygon should solve my problem.